# How to force a certain TLS version in a PHP stream context for the ssl:// transport?

Tags: php, ssl

How can I force TLSv1.0 in a PHP stream context when trying to access an `https` URL?

I’m looking for something along the lines of this:

```php
$context = stream_context_create(
  array(
    'ssl' => array(
      'protocol_version' => 'tls1',
    ),
  ));
file_get_contents('https://example.com/test', false, $context);
```

#### Background

Actually I’m facing [an issue in Ubuntu 12.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371) when working with PHP’s [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapclient.php). Unfortunately, the server I’m trying to connect to does only support SSLv3.0/TLSv1.0 and fails on the default TLSv1.1 negotiation. Therefore I’d like to explicitly set the protocol of the `ssl://` transport to TLSv1.0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**PHP 5.6+ Users**

This is a new feature as documented on the [PHP 5.6 OpenSSL Changes page](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php#migration56.openssl.crypto-method).

<strike>At time of writing this, PHP5.6 is in Beta1 and thus this isn't overly useful. People of the future - lucky you!</strike>

The future is upon us. PHP 5.6 is a thing and its use should be encouraged. Be aware that it deprecates some fairly widely used things like mysql_* functions so care should be taken when upgrading.

**Everyone else**

@toubsen is correct in his answer - this isn't directly possible. To elaborate on his suggested workarounds... when working around a problem where a supplier's API server wasn't correctly negotiating TLSv1.2 down to its supported TLSv1.0, sending a small subset of ciphers seemed to allow negotiation to complete correctly. Stream context code is:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    [
        'ssl' => [
            'ciphers' => 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:KRB5-DES-CBC3-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-MD5:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5:KRB5-RC4-MD5:KRB5-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:RC4-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-SHA:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-SHA:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5',
        ],
    ]
);
```

**SOAP Users**

PHP's SOAP client doesn't use curl, nor does it seem to use the default context set with `stream_context_set_default`. As such, the created context needs to be passed to the SOAPClient constructor in the 2nd parameter as such:

```
$soap_client = new SOAPClient('http://webservices.site.com/wsdlfile.wsdl', array('stream_context' => $context));
```

**Why those Ciphers?**

Running the command `openssl ciphers` on the server gives you a list of supported ciphers in the above format. Running `openssl ciphers -v` tells you those that are TLSv1.2 specific. The above list was compiled from all of the non-TLSv1.2 ciphers reported by OpenSSL.

`openssl ciphers -v | grep -v 'TLSv1.2' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tr "\n" ':'`

Comment: While I can’t test this anymore (see my comment on [toubsen’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20072854/1797912)), this seems to be the right answer. I assume they wouldn’t have added the `crypto_method` SSL context option to PHP 5.6 if there would have been any other solution in previous PHP versions. So we’ll probably have to live with the described workarounds until PHP 5.6 can be used in production. Thanks!

Comment: Using `'ciphers'` in PHP 5.4 seems to restrict the ciphers, so picking only ciphers defined for TLSv1.2 should work in 5.4 as well.

Comment: This solution worked in PHP 7.0 and openssl 1.0.2k for a server that would not negotiate TLS1.2 and would not renegotiate down to TLS1.0. Spent WAY too much time getting this working.

Answer (score 7):

In case someone wants to know how to "disable" TLSv1.0 when making a SOAP request...

```
$parameters = array(
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'DEFAULT:!TLSv1.0:!SSLv3'
        ),
    )),
    'connection_timeout' => 15
);

$client = new SoapClient(YOUR_WSDL_URL_HERE, $parameters);
```

The key part here is that stream context **ciphers** line. This says use the default ciphers, but exclude TLSv1.0 ciphers (the 1.0 package also has TLSv1.1 ciphers). The : is the cipher package separator (what goes between packages) and the ! here is to tell it to exclude this package (it's a hard exclude so if it shows up later in the list it will still be excluded). Soft exclude is - character and add to the end of the list is + character. To add in order just add it without anything in front of it.

Cipher information here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-LIST-FORMAT

Edit:
For whatever reason including the

```
'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
```

part from the options was really causing me headaches and wouldn't connect in certain contexts. After tons of troubleshooting and playing around with options I finally realized that removing this setting and letting it autoset this seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: I was unable to connect from PHP 5.5 to a server not accepting TLS1.1 any longer. Unfortunately using crypto_method is not an option as the constant STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT is new to PHP 5.6. Your Edit about removing 'ssl_method' solved the issue.

Comment: @David, glad to hear it! It took me forever to figure out what the heck was going on. You're right about that constant. I was having the same issue and wasn't able to use that either so I had to start looking for alternatives. THen I landed on the stream context. This worked somewhat and then I realized I needed to take out the old constant for the ssl method because it was forcing it back down to TLS 1.1 and hosing things up.

Comment: @David your suggest was useful, but in my case with PHP 5.5 just comment out the ssl_method solve the issue.

Comment: Beware that for this to work you also need a version of the OpenSSL libraries that supports the version of TLS you're trying to use. In my case, trying to force use of TLSv1.2, I needed OpenSSL 1.0.1 and above. `php -r 'echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT . "\n";'` showed "OpenSSL 0.9.8zc 19 Mar 2015", so I was out of luck, and getting "stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version". Upgrading to OpenSSL 1.0.2 made it connect successfully using TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 3):

**Base information**

The field `protocol_version` is only valid for HTTP context (HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1), but does not affect the SSL context.

The following manual page lists all stream context options for PHP:
[Context options and parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.php)

For all SSL based stream wrappers, only the follwing options are available:
[SSL context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php)

**Possible solutions / workarounds**

First advice: Get the server admin to fix his server instead of working around this in your client ;-)

Maybe you can get it wo work with the [`ciphers` option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.ciphers) for SSL streams, to pass only one exact [TLSv1.0 cipher suite](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#TLS_v1_0_cipher_suites_) (that is unique to TLSv1.0) in the list, that your target server supports.

Switching the implementaion to use cURL will most probaly also not help here, as according to [an entry in their mailing list](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-04/0371.html), there's no option to force a certain TLS version - the client will downgrade when needed automatically.

**tl;dr**

I currently know of no way to explicitly force TLSv1.0 for SSL connections from PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately – or actually luckily – the problem I had was eventually resolved on the server side. At first I had no chance of convincing the admins but obviously they have updated their server in the meantime. Still this background information and workaround suggestions may be helpful to others who are facing similar issues. As for your suggestion with the `ciphers` option: I think I had tried that back then without success; but I don’t properly remember. Now I can’t test it anymore …

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that above accepted answer does not work for Ubuntu 12.04 and PHP 5.4.33 combination. Also found out that I have to manually specify certificate when trying openssl and curl to access https endpoints. I ended up using RHEL 7 and PHP 5.5 to achieve a solid solution as I was developing integration for an enterprise application. Nothing against Ubuntu, but in my specific case it didn't work.