# How to force TLS 1.2 with SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, tls1.2

I am using a PSP that recently switched to only support TLS 1.2 (as per PCI-DSS).

Within a php7 application, I can connect to their SOAP API. However, since their upgrade I am getting an SSL error indicating their server does not support my TLS version. I ran a wireshark and can confirm there is only a `client hell`o, so `server hello` and it is on TLS 1.0.

I am using the following code:

```
$this->soapClient = new SoapClient('some/wsdl'), [
    'location' => 'https://endpoint.of.server',
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
        'ssl' => [
            'local_cert' =>  '/path/to/client.crt',
            'crypto_method' =>  STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
        ],
    ])
]);
```

However, this code still uses TLS 1.0 and not the desired TLS 1.2.

**Versions**

`OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018`

`PHP 7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) ( NTS )`.

Comment: Hi George, did you find the answer to this question? I have a similar setup and the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the above code is 100% correct.

In my case, the error lay somewhere in the certificate. For still unknown reasons, our self-generated SSL client certificate did not cope well with TLS 1.2. After we generated a new certificate, everything worked like magic.

**Things I've tried / verified**

- Make sure your have a supported `openssl` verion (>= 1.0.1)
- Consider manually specifying the ciphers
- Debug the connection using Wireshark to verify the protocol

Also, take a look at [How to force a certain TLS version in a PHP stream context for the ssl:// transport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547163/how-to-force-a-certain-tls-version-in-a-php-stream-context-for-the-ssl-transp)