# PHP file_get_contents() SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, xml, ssl, simplexml, file-get-contents

I'd like to preface this question with "**I am an idiot**" but I could really use some help.

I have a PHP site hosted by GoDaddy. I have been using file_get_contents() to read a simple XML page for the past several years into the mySQL database for my site. This January I started getting the below warnings.

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Failed to enable crypto

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.competitionsuite.com/2013-02/Competitions/?o=C35091BF-0F25-4C86-A5AA-C7714E38112C) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream

I did not have an SSL Certificate for the site before this, so I purchased the basic one from GoDaddy hoping this would resolve the error but even on the HTTPS site I get the same errors.

Here is a snippet of my code, but if I need to provide more please let me know.

```
//read XML
$url = 'https://api.competitionsuite.com/2013-02/Competitions/?o=C35091BF-0F25-4C86-A5AA-C7714E38112C';
$context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
                            
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

I could really use some guidance if anyone has a spare moment. TIA

Comment: Its not your certificate its compaining about. Seems like the other end upgraded something (allowed cyphers maybe) and your end cannot keep up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547163/how-to-force-a-certain-tls-version-in-a-php-stream-context-for-the-ssl-transp

Comment: This is a little over my head, but is the gist that there's nothing I can do?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.2.17

Comment: I have no proof (have not got time to go back that far into history, 5.2 stopped being supported 10 years ago) but it sounds like the server you are getting the data FROM has removed all the old unsafe cyphers and more than likely your PHP is so old the new safe once were not even invented when PHP5.2 was released. I think you are going to have to upgrade your PHP, but that in itself is going to be a SERIOUS Job as 5.2 is ancient

Comment: oh wow, I honestly had no idea. i use GoDaddy for hosting and I just use whatever they have installed by default. I never thought about it being so far behind.

Comment: Thank you so much @RiggsFolly for having me check out the PHP Version. I updated to PHP version: 5.4.19, which is still not the latest, but that solved my problem with this error and didn't break any of my other php code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right on. This or the other end server is not well configured.