# PHP: server to server TLS connection

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, https, tls1.2

I need to establish a `TLS` connection between my backend and a web service API. I'm using the `HttpClientInterface` class within the Symfony framework. I would really like to understand what I'm doing here.

This is the situation:

1. I recieved a `.p12` file containing my certificate and its private key, these have been extracted with openssl to `.pem` files. In the `PHP: SSL context options`, I have set `local_cert = /mypath/mycert.pem`, `local_pk = /mypath/mykey.pem` and `passphrase = 'pwtoextractfiles'`. **Are all these options neccessary? Whats happening here really?**
2. I also got a server certificate. I set `cafile = /mypath/servercert.pem`. However the issuer of the server cert tells me I'm supposed to add the *issuer* of the server cert as *trusted root* and add the issuer in my trust store. **How is this done in PHP? Have I done this correctly by setting the cafile option?**

Comment: First, if you use `https` in the URL, you will have a secure transport. (If you actually need to enforce TLS over SSL, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23130512/231316)). Your client, however might not trust that cert, but try running it first before you go down a rabbit hole. If it doesn’t work, I’d set the [CA file](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cafile) for your client, probably making a scoped client. Your endpoint might also want a client certificate and/or for you to “pin” their cert, I’d confirm with them.

Comment: Thanks once again @ChrisHaas for a good answer. I did some trial and error and managed to get a response from the server - without referencing the server cert in PHP. Instead, I installed the cert as trusted root CA in my windows system. Do you think that did the trick? If yes, will I be able to do a similar installation once I set up my page at a hosting provider? (I have limited experience with configuring servers) Or should I remove it from windows and reference the server cert in my PHP application?

Comment: The way you did it works if you control the entire server. If you are on shared hosting, you’ll need to find a less-global way